# How to check if a User is part of a Group or not in a UI extension

Tags: gui-extensions

I am trying to implement a GUI extension where I want the extension to be accessible only to the Users who are part of a certain user Group. How do I achieve this using the Anguilla framework?

Comment: Pl. indicate if this is for 2013 or 2011. It would help the readers. The difference is highlighted below, if you want to play with the XML The response from the API: var xml = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getInstance().getXmlDocument(); is different between the two versions. To recurse through grpmemberships: var grpMemShip = xml.getElementsByTagName("tcm:GroupMemberships"); For 2011 we need to use the property childnodes but in 2013 its children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this in the `_isAvailable` method you implemented in your command Javascript, optionally you can also do this in the `_isEnabled` method.

In there you will have to check what Group the User belongs to. To get the current User and its Groups you can use the following:

```js
var settings = Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true);
if (settings)
{
    var groups = settings.User.Data.GroupMemberships;
}
```

Now the `groups` parameter will be be an object array containing the Groups the current User belongs to, they are formatted as JSON with a `type`, `title` and `href` (the TCMURI).

Now please note that Administrator users are usually not assigned to any Groups specifically (because they have all rights coming from their Administrator status already). Such a user will also not have an array of Groups in its `GroupMemberships`, but that will just contain one object (the Group "Everyone" for an Administrator).

To identify if a user is an Administrator, you can check out `settings.User.Data.Privileges`, that will have the value `1` (for an Administrator).

Comment: Tried accessing groups as an array, not able to iterate through the array. tried getting length using alert(groups.length); values comes up as 'undefined'

Comment: Try `settings.User.Data.GroupMemberships` in your browser Console (after you have set the `settings` variable) and you will see what it contains. The browser developer tools and its Console window are really your best friend when developing UI extensions. When I request `settings.User.Data.GroupMemberships.length` it returns 3 but my user is part of 3 groups, if your user is a standard Administrator it might just be part of the group Everyone only, which will not show as an array indeed, but just the info of that Group (which might be a problem for your check of course).

Comment: +1. I think this type of setup may also need to check for (or intentionally ignore) "subgroup" scenarios (e.g. user belongs to "Global Author" which belongs to "Author"). Does GroupMemberships include *parents* of the user's immediate group?

Comment: @AlvinReyes I'm pretty sure that only the actual memberships are listed, so I'm expecting if rights are set using groups and subgroups, then the code in this extension will become a lot more complicated. On the other hand, there must be a way to check rights against groups, as that is what the UI does. So next to determining which group memberships the user has, there might also be some functions around that in the API.

Comment: Good point, we see the UI check rights/scope/permissions in the list of publications, how tabs display, schema and template drop-downs, etc. :-)