# How to remove access to tridion user avoid remove pages from publishing queue

Tags: 2011, user-management, permissions, user-rights

How to remove access to tridion user avoid remove pages from publishing queue

We have a User with Default Chief Editor Group and have Access to All publciation  and they are able to remove the items from Publishing Queue.

is there a way we can restrict the User to avoid remove pages from publishing queue.

Tridion Version : Tridion 2011 SP1

Answer (score 2):

The one obvious way would be to remove the publishing permission however doing that will also remove the permission to publish.

As per your description, it seems, you just want to remove permission to remove from publishing queue however not block the publishing for the users of that group.

> In such a scenario, you can develop a GUI extension which will disable
>   the option to remove from publishing. In GUI extension you can easily
>   get current user and from that user you can get group membership:
>   [reference](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-group-or-not-in-a-ui-extension)

**Now check if user is part of the group mentioned then disable the option to remove from publishing queue.**

As suggested by Nuno, other option is to write event system that will trigger on delete of transaction initiated and will throw excpetion to block the operation.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, you want to block permission for testgroup or not.

Comment: Thanks Hiren, In one of my production environment, I have a user and added to a group ( TestGroup) and  TestGroup is the member of  Default Editor Group and have access to only few publication. If you go to the properties of the publication ,they have following rights , Folder,Component,Page,publish to Content Distributor,Virtual Folder, so when I login as this user , go to publishing queue, I see the publishing queue option is disabled.

Comment: Probably even easier would be an event that fires on delete for PublishTransaction, then throw an exception

Comment: @NunoLinhares - Yes, agreed. It depends on user experience whether to disable option or to give message when action is performed. Both options seems to be valid.

Comment: I'd be careful to ensure you write the group(s) that you want to restrict deletion of publish queue items to be configurable - and perhaps to include specific users also (if your requirement _may extend in the future_) as it's something that would be easy to add in the beginning. 

Given that - you could just create a _'unable to delete publish queue items'_ group ( _perphaps a slightly less verbose name would suit too_ ) - and you could then traverse through group/user memberships and control very easily with a fully-extensible solution)